# How to get the geocoderControl textbox value from mapbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, mapbox

i am using map box geocodercontrol fr searching the place. how to get that autocomplete textbox value from JavaScript

Comment: 1. What have you already tried? 2. Why didn't it work? 3. Share the code you've tried.

Comment: map = map.addControl(L.mapbox.geocoderControl('mapbox.places-v1', 
        {
            autocomplete: true,
            keepOpen: false             
    }));

Comment: i am not getting the builtin textbox value. how to get that value from that textbox